# Passing vm arguments to exec-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jvm-arguments, java-17, exec-maven-plugin

Guys I have upgraded my project to Java 17 that's why I need these lines to VM to my program works without error.

> =--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

My project is working but I have another sub project which I use for testing purposes.It is run on JavaFX and it need previous arguments to work correctly.
I have tried adding as CommandLineArgs and arguments but still arguments are not passing through to vm and giving errors.

```
    <profile>
        <id>smoke</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy jars for tests</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                                <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                        <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                        <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                        <executable>${env.HOME}/java/bin/java.exe</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>

                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-javaagent:${env.HOME}/wildfly/standalone/lib/ext/agent.jar</argument>
                            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <argument>lib/*;classes</argument>
                            <argument>-DJBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME}</argument>
                            <argument>-DJAVA_HOME=${env.HOME}/java</argument>
                            <argument>-Duser.home=${env.USERPROFILE}</argument>
                            <argument>-Djava.library.path=${JBOSS_HOME}/bin</argument>

                            <argument>-DTESTING_FROM_COMMANDLINE=true</argument>
                            <mainClass>com.test.GenerateSmoke</mainClass>
                  <commandlineArgs>-Dexec.args=--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</commandlineArgs>

                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

If you have any idea please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when running tests with the maven-surefire-plugin.
In my case I added it like this into the pom:

```
<configuration>
                <argLine>${argLine} --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
</configuration>
```

Maybe it is the same in your case.

Comment: `argLine` is not part of this plugin definition; see https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

The plugins configuration options are documented here: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

`commandlineArgs` or `-Dexec.args` are both an alternative option to override the entire executed command line you specify. These can not be used together with (other) `arguments`.
So you either define the entire `java` command line to execute as:

- `arguments` in the pom, or
- `commandlineArgs` in the pom, or
- exec.args as an *environment variable* (so `mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args=...`)

You should be able to add the arguments to your current plugin configuration like so:

```
<configuration>
    <arguments>
        <argument>...</argument>
        <argument>--add-opens</argument>
        <argument>java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
        <argument>--add-opens</argument>
        <argument>java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
        <argument>...</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Depending on what you run these arguments might need to be inserted in a specific place, so the order of these arguments matters.
That is where you can experiment with substituting the `...` in my example with your current arguments.

As a test i've ran a `java -jar` with these options, and that works. I've enabled the maven argument `-X` for debug logging.

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [some\path\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe, --add-opens, java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, -jar, my.jar]
```

And if i make an "accidental" typo in my `add-opens` we see that these arguments are indeed parsed by the java process:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [some\path\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe, --add-typo, java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, -jar, my.jar]
Unrecognized option: --add-typo
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```